# How to get sum value of unique ID's only ONCE in Tableau

Tags: left-join, tableau-api

I'm using Tableau Desktop 10.2

I have multiple data sources that are joined together through left joins:
[Data Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kx0ov.png)

This causes an issue for me as I'd like to get the total of my pipeline (yellow box). Right now, because of the way I've joined everything, my pipeline is huge since all the ID's are being added:

ID - Value ($M)

1234 - $100M

5678 - $50M

5678 - $50M

1234 - $100M

1234 - $100M

9101 - $20M

Right now, my total value is $420M, when it should be $170M.

I'd like to keep the joins because my dashboards contain filters I'd like to affect worksheets.

Any idea on what I can do?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your worksheet for the example that you have given?

Answer (score 0):

You could do a LOD calculation on ID and Sum the calculation if your data looks like the above example.
If you are not filtering with other parameters, your LOD calculation would be:

```
{Fixed [ID]: SUM(Value ($M))}
```

then do a `SUM(LOD calcuation above)`

Let's say you would like to filter by date, just simply add the parameter into the LOD calculation:

```
{Fixed [ID], [Date]: SUM(Value ($M))}
```

Then sum the LOD calculation as mentioned before.